# Communicate with Pi via Instant Messaging

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I'm currently working on a kitchen inventory system using a Raspberry Pi. I thought it would be fun to use an instant messaging service to access the inventory from remote and send the Pi commands, however I wasn't able to find anything useful.

I stumbled upon a WhatsApp library called `yowsup2`, but apparently it will stop working at the end of June because WhatsApp is changing their protocol.

I know about DynDNS and Port Forwarding to access a website with the inventory running on the Pi, but I consider it a last resort if nothing else works.

Comment: How do you plan to secure such a system? As a rule of thumb when you can't find any existing work or examples it generally means one of two things - the idea is novel or there are better means to the same end.

Comment: You could use Facebook's [bot feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/bots).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Twitter API and create an account for the PI, have it use that as it's output which will obviously need to be truncated or paged.  The upside is that if you sent that account to private and have it only listen to followed users for commands you could have the wife and your accounts on there.